# updating columns using for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

my dataset has 60 variables, each variables has ordinal value with 5 levels (Agree, Disagree, Neutral, Strongly Agree, Strongly Disagree), but it is showing 6 levels with addition of level **" "**. I want to remove that unnecessary level from all the columns. I am using the code

```
for (i in colnames(shopping[,11:60])){   
    shopping$i <- factor(shopping$i)   
}
```

but after executing the code I am getting the following error

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "i", value = integer(0)) : 
>     replacement has 0 rows, data has 162

Can someone help me?

Comment: `for (i in colnames(shopping)[11:60]) shopping[, i] <- factor(shopping[, i])`

Comment: Please use `dput(shopping)` to show your data. Read [mcve] and edit your question!

Comment: Have a look at `?droplevels`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve your looping problem

```
for (i in seq_along(shopping[, 11:60])){   

 shopping[i] <- factor(shopping[[i]])  

}
```

Is there an " " value in these columns also? If so, you can fix that you can solve without an explicit loop using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

var1 <- c('Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Strongly Agree', 'Strongly Disagree', '" "')
var2 <- c('Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Strongly Agree', 'Strongly Disagree', '" "')
df <- data.frame(var1, var2)

               var1              var2
1             Agree             Agree
2          Disagree          Disagree
3           Neutral           Neutral
4    Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree
5 Strongly Disagree Strongly Disagree
6                ""                ""

df %>% 
  na_if(., '" "') %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  droplevels()

               var1               var2
1             Agree             Agree
2          Disagree          Disagree
3           Neutral           Neutral
4    Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree
5 Strongly Disagree Strongly Disagree
```